# how to manipulate, merge and overwrite data store is list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

sorry guys this is a very Difficult question leave it.
Hi guys I have two separate lists containing many dictionaries, and I need to overwrite the dictionary values to another dictionary.

```
list1 = [
    ('English', 80, 100, [
        {'subcode_001': 90, 'subcode_002': 93, 'subcode_003': 98},
        {'subcode_001': 81, 'subcode_002': 87, 'subcode_003': 89}
    ]),
    ('mathematics', 90, 100, [
        {'subcode_006': 99, 'subcode_007': 98, 'subcode_009': 91},
        {'subcode_006': 96, 'subcode_007': 7, 'subcode_008': 92}
    ])
]

list2 = [
    ('Class_10', [
        {'subcode_001': 0, 'subcode_002': 0, 'subcode_003': 0, 'subcode_004': 89, 'subcode_005': 90},
        {'subcode_001': 10, 'subcode_002': 0, 'subcode_003': 10, 'subcode_004': 78, 'subcode_005': 60}
    ]),
    ('class_11', [
        {'subcode_006': 0, 'subcode_007': 0, 'subcode_008': 0, 'subcode_009': 0},
        {'subcode_006': 0, 'subcode_007': 0, 'subcode_008': 0, 'subcode_009': 0}
    ])
]
```

In the above `list1` has some subject marks and `list2` has all the subjects, so I need to overwrite the key, `list1` to `list2`, and create output like this:

```
output = [
    ('class_10', 80, 100, [
        {'subcode_001': 90, 'subcode_002': 93, 'subcode_003':98, 'subcode_004': 89, 'subcode_005': 90},
        {'subcode_001': 81, 'subcode_002': 87, 'subcode_003':89, 'subcode_004': 78, 'subcode_005': 60}
    ]),
    ('class_11', 90, 100, [
        {'subcode_006': 99, 'subcode_007': 98, 'subcode_008': 0, 'subcode_009': 91},
        {'subcode_006': 96, 'subcode_007': 7, 'subcode_008': 92, 'subcode_009': 0}
    ])
]
```

Comment: What determines, for example, that "English" corresponds with "Class_10"

Comment: @user650881 Hi we can determine with the key present in both of the list

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that the entries of the two lists match in their order, i.e the first element of lists 1 matches with the first element of list 2 (otherwise you would need some form of dictionary macthing the elements of both lists):

```
output = []
for tup1, tup2 in zip(list1,list2):
    add_up_dics = []
    for dic1, dic2 in zip(tup1[-1],tup2[-1]):
        for key,value in dic1.items():
            if key in dic2:
                dic2[key] = max(dic2[key],value)
            else:
                dic2[key] = value
        add_up_dics.append(dic2)
    output.append((tup2[0],*tup1[1:3],add_up_dics))
```

Comment: Hi this code is working but I need list2 all dictionary values overwrite by list1 like this: ('class_10', 80, 100, [
        {'subcode_001': 90, 'subcode_002': 93, 'subcode_003':98, 'subcode_004': 89, 'subcode_005': 90},
        {'subcode_001': 81, 'subcode_002': 87, 'subcode_003':89, 'subcode_004': 78, 'subcode_005': 60}
    ])

Comment: Ah okay, missed that the dictionaries also need to be merged, edited my solution

Comment: Hi @Niklas could you please help me https://stackoverflow.com/q/65041969/14455698